# How can i find bicomponents in graph ? called block

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

Here my tryings, and copypastings. But what i must write to find biconnectedcomponent (called block)?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
ifstream cin ("test3.txt");
ofstream cout ("output.txt");

const int l = 6;
int G[l][l];
int MAXN; 
int used[l];
int number[l], low[l], counter = 1, kids = 0;
vector <int> block[l];

void BiComp(int curr, int prev) {
    int kids = 0;
    low[curr] = number[curr] = counter++;
    used[curr] = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAXN; i++) {
        if(G[curr][i] == 1) {
            if (i != prev) {
                if (used[i] == 0) {

                    kids++;
                    block[0].push_back(curr);
                    block[0].push_back(i);
                    BiComp(i, curr);
                    low[curr] = min(low[curr], low[i]);
                    if(low[i] >= number[curr] && (prev != -1 || kids >= 2)) {
                        cout << "tochka " << curr + 1 << endl;

                    }



                } else {

                    block[0].push_back(i);
                    block[0].push_back(prev);
                    cout<<block<<endl;
                    low[curr] = min(low[curr], number[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void main() 
{
    MAXN = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXN; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAXN; j++)
        {
            cin >> G[i][j];
            cout << G[i][j] << " "; 
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //for (int i = 0; i < MAXN; i++) {
        //if (number[i] == 0) {
            BiComp(0, -1);
        //}
    //}
}
```

How can i find by this code, finding cutpoints at the same time blocks??? 
In graph theory, a biconnected component (or 2-connected component) is a maximal biconnected subgraph.

Comment: so what's wrong with the code you show?

Comment: i don't understad algoritm of finding blocks so i don't know how to write it

Answer (score 0):

Ok what comes to my mind is a very brute-force approach that isn't going to scale well, but I also remember reading that finding biconnected components is in fact a hard problem, computationally, so let's just start with it and then see if there's optimizations to be done.

Given a set of N nodes, check for each possible subset of nodes whether they form a biconnected component. Typically, you'll want the biggest component available, so just start with the whole graph, then with all subgraphs of N-1 nodes, N-2, and so on. As soon as you find one solution, you'll know you have found one of the biggest possible size and you can quite. Still, you'll end up checking 2^N subgraphs in the worst case. So start with a loop constructing your graphs to be tested.

To find out if a given graph with K nodes is a biconnected component, loop over all K*(K-1)/2 pairs of nodes and find out if there are two independent paths between them.

In order to find out if two nodes i and j are biconnected, first find all paths between them. For each path, find out if there is an alternative connection to that path. If you find one, you're done for that pair. If not, you've found proof that the graph you're looking at is not biconnected and you can break from all loops but the outer one and test the next graph.

In order to see if there is an alternative connection between i and j, take out all edges you used in the first path, and see if you can find another one. If you can, you're fine with i and j. If you can't, continue with the next path in the initial list of paths you found. If you reach the end of your list of paths without finding one for which an alternative exists when taking out the involved edges, the two nodes are not biconnected and hence the whole graph isn't.

Comment: [http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шарнир_(теория_графов)]     (12, 2345, 56) - are blocks, that is what i meen

Comment: well you would get 2345 from the algorithm I proposed above. However, in the English version of the Wikipedia entry, you also get a proposal for an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There is a linear run time algorithm for finding all cut points (or cut vertices or articulation points) in a given graph using Depth First Search.

Once you found all the cut points, it's easy to find all of the bicomponents.